# MySQL select distinct rows for same group using table1.id REGEXP table2.id

Tags: php, mysql, sql, regex

Table name: groups

```
id  name
1   ONE
2   TWO
3   THREE
4   FOUR
5   FIVE
6   SIX
```

Table name: titles

```
id  title           groups  isactive
1   First Title     1,2,4   yes
2   Second Title    2,5,7   yes
3   Third Title     3,1,2   yes
4   Fourth title    2,4,5   yes
```

Link column: id

QUERY:

```
SELECT 
 t.*, g.name
FROM 
 `titles` AS t, groups AS g 
WHERE 
  t.groups REGEXP CONCAT('^', g.id, '')
ORDER by title ASC, name ASC
```

Results:

```
id  title           groups  isactive    name
1   First Title     1,2,4   yes         ONE
4   Fourth title    2,4,5   yes         TWO
2   Second Title    2,5,7   yes         TWO
3   Third Title     3,1,2   yes         THREE
```

Now, the problem is I want to select only one title for each group, however, there might be duplicate group names like (id = 4 and 2) both assigned to group number TWO.

HOW TO ONLY SHOW THE ONE WITH HIGH ID? Then the result should be like this: (excluding id=2)

```
id  title           groups  isactive    name
1   First Title     1,2,4   yes         ONE
4   Fourth title    2,4,5   yes         TWO
3   Third Title     3,1,2   yes         THREE
```

I tried using this query also:

```
SELECT 
 t.*, g.name
FROM 
 `titles` AS t, groups AS g 
WHERE 
  t.groups REGEXP CONCAT('^', g.id, '')
GROUP by g.name
ORDER by t.id DESC
```

or

```
ORDER by t.id ASC
```

But both showing:

```
id  title           groups  isactive   name
3   Third Title     3,1,2   yes        THREE
2   Second Title    2,5,7   yes        TWO
1   First Title     1,2,4   yes        ONE
```

PLEASE SEE [DEMO - SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/aae12/1)

Comment: Just an information; You should consider using many-to-many relationship

Comment: @CanGeliş: thanks, I knew that, however, this is just a simpler scenario for the real case which I can't change it easily.

Comment: There is no need to use Regex. You can use some of the string functions to retract the first part of the `groups` column.

Comment: @ypercube: the regex here is for test, how if I want to match the id with 3,5,7 with (5)?

Comment: You can use the `FIND_IN_SET()` function to extract all ids from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT A.*, B.NAME FROM titles A
JOIN (
         SELECT g.name, max(t.id) id
         FROM titles AS t, groups AS g 
         WHERE t.groups REGEXP CONCAT('^', g.id, '')
         group by g.name
     ) B on A.id = b.id
```

[SQL DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/aae12/16)